# Plotly and IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, plotly

The below code executes fine but without displaying the window I am waiting for. I believe it's a problem due to my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA), which just launches the console impeding it from displaying any window. How could I solve that ? Is there any option within the IDE to check e.g. ?

```
import co.theasi.plotly.{Plot, draw}

object Main {
  def main(args : Array[String]) : Unit = {

    val xs = 0.0 to 2.0 by 0.1
    val ys = xs.map { x => x*x }
    val plot = Plot().withScatter(xs, ys)
    draw(plot, "my-first-plot")

  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try running it from the console to see if it works from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't look like this is a capability of the plot.ly library for scala(unlike [wisp](https://github.com/quantifind/wisp)). `draw(plot, "my-first-plot")` pushes a plot file to plot.ly, which can be viewed by [logging into your plot.ly account](https://plot.ly/accounts/login/?action=login) and navigating to *My Files*. There you can see the plots that have been pushed to plot.ly. [Based on the docs](https://plot.ly/scala/user-guide/), it seems the only way to view your docs is by pushing them to a plot.ly server via an instance of `writer.Server`.

You can of course [procure an on-premise plot.ly](https://plot.ly/products/on-premise/) server for a mere $9,950.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this info](https://asidatascience.github.io/scala-plotly-client/latest/api/#co.theasi.plotly.package)

> Plotly is a platform for creating and hosting plots. This library lets you create, modify and delete **plots on Plotly.**
>
> Build a plot using Plot, and **send that plot to the Plotly servers** with draw.

So, what window you waiting for in this case?

Comment: I don't have any window. Plotly's examples don't show any creation and/or displaying of a window.